# EarlyUpdate.Preloading in Unity profiler

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I have some performance-related issue with my WebGL unity3d project. For its solution, I am trying to profile my game and found some wired result that [EarlyUpdate.UpdatePreloading](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Experimental.PlayerLoop.EarlyUpdate.UpdatePreloading.html) sometime taking 76% and around 100kb GC allocaion. A brief search showed that it [was a bug](https://forum.unity.com/threads/loading-updatepreloading-taking-up-precious-time-for-no-reason.252578/) but I am using unity 2019.1.0 and it is still showing.
[image]

My question is that is this normal?

Comment: is that when running it from the IDE or when monitoring it as run in a website?

Comment: it is in unity editor (software)

Comment: You have to remember that when running from inside the unity IDE, because you can make changes while its live, it makes a copy of absolutely everything so it can do a "before and after" type thing.. This can be a significant hold up in the run process from within the IDE - to truly profile, you would need to attach the profiler to the running inside a browser when not running inside the IDE